# How to retry upon async/await function catching error?

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, try-catch, settimeout

I'm fairly new to JS and programming in general, and I've encountered the following problem while trying to implement try/catch into my async function. It looks sth like this:

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        await myFunc();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    setTimeout(main, 2000);
}) ();
```

As you can see, it's looped by setTimeout call to itself, making it infinite... unless it catches error. Naturally, I want to attempt to retry myFunc in certain instances of e, but have no idea how to make it without removing setTimeout (and a 2s delay here is important).

I tried to use labels:

```
let critErrCount;

(async function main() {
    critErrCount = 0;
    lbl:
    try {
        await myFunc();
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof errType1) {
            console.log(`errType1: ${e}`);
            continue lbl;
        } else if (e instanceof errType2) {
            critErrCount += 1;
            console.log(`errType2: ${e}`);
            console.log(`critErrCount: ${critErrCount}`);

            if (critErrCount == 5) {
                console.log(`Too many critErrs, aborting...`)
                process.exit;
            }
            continue lbl;
        } else { 
            process.exit
        }
    }

    setTimeout(main, 2000);
}) ();
```

And surely enough, it didn't work, because, as I learned , 'continue' does not behave like 'goto' in other languages, and only works in proper loops (forEach, while, for, etc.). Since setTimeout inside a catch block won't work either due to nodejs runtime specifics (showed as 'Illegal continue statement'), I'm out of ideas.

Comment: *making it infinite... unless it catches error.* Even if there's an error, the recursive `setTimeout` will still work, right?

Comment: why didn't you use `setInterval` ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance That is correct. But here's the catch: after some testing, I've determined that if `main` function caught error even once, it will self-terminate after several (the number is always different) iterations for unknown reasons. If no errors were caught, it will continue to work as expected until even one error is caught

Comment: I'm pretty sure the given code cannot result in what you say. Can you edit a live snippet into the question that shows the timeout eventually failing? I'd *think* that it would always work

Comment: @fadeys.work `setInterval` has no regard for function execution time, and my objective is to wait `2000` secs **after** the code has been executed

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd be happy to, but I don't know whether it will work since I'm using a library (through `require`). The name of the library is `ccxt`, if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a retry mechanism which could let you retry an async function call the number of times you want. [In this blogpost](https://bpaulino.com/entries/retrying-api-calls-with-exponential-backoff), I wrote how you can do that, but here is the implementation:

```js
/**
 * Execute a promise and retry with exponential backoff
 * based on the maximum retry attempts it can perform
 * @param {Promise} promise promise to be executed
 * @param {function} onRetry callback executed on every retry
 * @param {number} maxRetries The maximum number of retries to be attempted
 * @returns {Promise} The result of the given promise passed in
 */
function retry(promise, onRetry, maxRetries) {
  // Notice that we declare an inner function here
  // so we can encapsulate the retries and don't expose
  // it to the caller. This is also a recursive function
  async function retryWithBackoff(retries) {
    try {
      // Make sure we don't wait on the first attempt
      if (retries > 0) {
        // Here is where the magic happens.
        // on every retry, we exponentially increase the time to wait.
        // Here is how it looks for a `maxRetries` = 4
        // (2 ** 1) * 100 = 200 ms
        // (2 ** 2) * 100 = 400 ms
        // (2 ** 3) * 100 = 800 ms
        const timeToWait = 2 ** retries * 100;
        console.log(`waiting for ${timeToWait}ms...`);
        await waitFor(timeToWait);
      }
      return await promise();
    } catch (e) {
      // only retry if we didn't reach the limit
      // otherwise, let the caller handle the error
      if (retries < maxRetries) {
        onRetry();
        return retryWithBackoff(retries + 1);
      } else {
        console.warn('Max retries reached. Bubbling the error up')
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }

  return retryWithBackoff(0);
}

/**
 * Wait for the given milliseconds
 * @param {number} milliseconds The given time to wait
 * @returns {Promise} A fulfiled promise after the given time has passed
 */
function waitFor(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

And here is how you can use that `retry` helper:

```js
/** Fake an API Call that fails for the first 3 attempts
 * and resolves on its fourth attempt.
 */
function generateFailableAPICall() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function () {
    if (counter < 3) {
      counter++;
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Simulated error"));
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve({ status: "ok" });
    }
  };
}

/*** Testing our Retry with Exponential Backoff */
async function test() {
  const apiCall = generateFailableAPICall();
  const result = await retry(
    apiCall,
    () => {
      console.log("onRetry called...");
    },
    4
  );

  console.log("result: ", result);
}

test();
```

Comment: Since I posted that question a year ago I rewrote my script from the ground up in a manner similar to what you proposed here, so your answer is quite fitting. Thanks